# How do I transform the data set into a dictionary inside the repo. I am using pyspark within foundry

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, dataset, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I created a fusion sheet data to be synced to the data set. now, I want to use that data set for creating a dictionary in the repo. I am using pyspark in the repo. later I want to use that dictionary to be passed so that it populates descriptions as it is in [Is there a tool available within Foundry that can automatically populate column descriptions? If so, what is it called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067415/is-there-a-tool-available-within-foundry-that-can-automatically-populate-column).

it would great if anyone can help me creating the dictionary from data set using pyspark in the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code would convert your pyspark dataframe into a list of dictionaries:

```py
fusion_rows = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), fusion_df.collect())
```

However, in your particular case, you can use the following snippet:

```py
col_descriptions = {row["column_name"]: row["description"] for row in fusion_df.collect()}
my_output.write_dataframe(
    my_input.dataframe(),
    column_descriptions=col_descriptions
)
```

Assuming your Fusion sheet would look like this:

```
+------------+------------------+
| column_name|       description|
+------------+------------------+
|       col_A| description for A|
|       col_B| description for B|
+------------+------------------+
```