# Is adding a column description via write_dataframe aware of the branch it is run on?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform

**Context:** I have seen that in version `1.184.0` and later I can add column descriptions within the transform function. [[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067415/is-there-a-tool-available-within-foundry-that-can-automatically-populate-column)] E.g.:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output


@transform(
    my_output=Output("/my/output"),
    my_input=Input("/my/input"),
)
def my_compute_function(my_input, my_output):
    my_output.write_dataframe(
        my_input.dataframe(),
        column_descriptions={
            "col_1": "col 1 description"
        }
    )
```

**Question:** Will this update dataset descriptions only on the branch I run the transformation on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You don't need to worry about changing the column descriptions in other branches. The column description only changes the description of the corresponding branch.