# PALANTIR-FOUNDRY: Can I propagate the column description?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a pipeline of transformations. Can a description of a given column upstream that is downstream across the pipeline be propagated?

So that one can just add the description upstream and then it is propagated downstream automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read and write column descriptions and typeclasses in foundry transforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697141/how-can-i-read-and-write-column-descriptions-and-typeclasses-in-foundry-transfor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now there's nothing that does this for you automatically; however since you can read and write the descriptions from your Python like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697141/how-can-i-read-and-write-column-descriptions-and-typeclasses-in-foundry-transfor?noredirect=1&lq=1) you can do this on your own